# binutils build fails because of pex-unix file

Tags: binutils, msys2

I want to cross-compile GCC.  I am using MSYS2 as a shell, and mingw-w64 as the compiler.

I have downloaded binutils-2.25 and I configure with:

```
../binutils/./configure --target=sh3eb-elf --prefix=C:/tempinstall/ --disable-nls
```

I get an error when I try to build `binutils` on `libiberty/pex-unix` file:

> In function 'pex_wait':
> error: 'F_GETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
> error: 'FD_CLOEXEC' undeclared (first use in this function)
> error: 'F_SETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
> error: 'F_DUPFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> In function 'restore_fd':
> error: 'FD_CLOEXEC' undeclared (first use in this function)
> error: 'F_SETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> In function 'pex_unix_fdopenw':
> error: 'F_SETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
> error: 'FD_CLOEXEC' undeclared (first use in this function)

I have built the same compiler few months ago without problems. But I have since changed OS(Windows 7 to W10) and compiler(MinGW-GCC 4.8 to Mingw64-GCC 4.9)

I followed [this tutorial](http://prizm.cemetech.net/index.php?title=PrizmSDK_Setup_Guide#Other_Distributions)

Comment: I find a strange line on libiberty/config.log `pexecute = "pex-unix"`. Maybe configure don't detect Windows 10. Do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution:

I use MSys2 with msys2_shell that defines *-*-msys as host system.

But when I use mingw32_shell( that defines *-*-mingw32 as host), GNU-Make compile pex-win32 and it's works fine

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, by default, when running GNU `configure` scripts under MSYS2, the `build` and `host` system is reported as `i686-pc-msys`, or `x86_64-pc-msys` .

However , the configure script for `binutils` (and `gcc`) does not recognize `msys` in the third part , so the build defaults to a Unix build.  This , in turn, leads to `pex-unix` being compiled, which requres the POSIX features in `sys/wait.h`, which is not provided by MinGW-w64.

The configure scripts do have special cases for targets `mingw*` and `cygwin*`, which lead to compiling `pex-win32.c` instead, avoiding the problem.

---

I think the intended solution is that when we want to build using MinGW-w64, we should launch MSYS2 using the shortcut "MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit" or "MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit".  These shortcuts set up environment variables so that the Host string is set to `i686-w64-mingw32` or `i686-w64-mingw64` (or `x86_64` instead of `i686` in both cases if you used 64-bit MSYS2).  Then the binutils configure script picks up its `mingw` case and build the right thing.

However, compiling binutils-2.28, even though it did try to build `pex-win32.c`, I got a bunch of compile errors: `_open` was not declared, and so on.

I did not investigate this further because I tried something else first which turned out to work: I launched the standard MSYS2 shell (not the MinGW-w64 variants), I put `/mingw32/bin` on the front of `PATH`, and I passed the argument `--build=i686-w64-mingw32` to `configure` for binutils and gcc.

This succeeded and I was able to build a complete cross toolchain (for arm-eabi v0 actually), which did not have MSYS2 dependency.

Comment: I'm not sure how you didn't get any upvotes for this response as this worked for me. The only difference is that I had to uninstall gcc from MSYS2 using `pacman -R gcc`, install MingW32 from [GitHub releases](https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases) and unzip it into the root drive, open the MingW64 terminal, set `PATH=${PATH}:/c/mingw32/bin`, run `configure` and then `make`.

Comment: I assume is this way because of the nature of the MSYS2 GCC compiler being POSIX compliant

Comment: @joe thanks for the comment. Low-traffic question I guess -- not many people doing this!